# React Native ternary operator display lag due to ajax request

Tags: ios, react-native, jsx

I have isRegistered that I fetch via ajax call so isRegistered takes an amount of time to be set.

```
        <View style={{ width: '48%' }}>
          <Text style={style.labelStyle}>

            {isRegistered ? 'Attempt' : 'Amount'}

          </Text>
        </View>
```

As a result I see 'Amount' first (a few hundred of milliseconds so noticeable by human) before I can see 'Attempt'

How can I avoid this?

I am developping on IOS emulator (not device) but wonder it will also happen on real device

Comment: I don't think you can completely avoid it.......you can just add some UI components until the state of isRegistered is obtained!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to show a loading indicator, etc. before the AJAX call completes if you want to avoid this behavior.

```
<View style={{ width: '48%' }}>
  { isLoading && (<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"><Text style={style.labelStyle}>{"Loading"}</Text></View> )}

  { !isLoading && (
  <Text style={style.labelStyle}>
    { isRegistered ? 'Attempt' : 'Amount'}
  </Text>
 )}
</View>
```

You may try making this AJAX call ahead of time, on a previous screen to avoid this behavior as well.